# Getting "DOMException: OTP retrieval was cancelled." when using WebOTP API

Tags: android, sms, autofill, sms-verification

I am testing WebOTP API for autofilling verification code using [WebOTP API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebOTP_API).

I'm trying to fill an HTML input element inside a cross-origin iframe. The iframe is a Preact app.

I added the following to the iframe code where the input lives:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if ('OTPCredential' in window) {
        const input = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>(
            'input[name="code-input-0"]',
        );
        if (!input) return;
        const ac = new AbortController();
        navigator.credentials
            .get({
                otp: { transport: ['sms'] },
                signal: ac.signal,
            })
            .then(otp => {
                input.value = otp!.code;
                ac.abort();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                ac.abort();
            });
    }
});
```

To support cross-origin iframes, I added `allow='otp-credentials'` attribute to the iframe tag.

However, when I navigate to the page with the input, I see `DOMException: OTP retrieval was cancelled.` in the console. When I send the text message, I see the prompt overlay asking to allow Chrome to read the message and enter the code. When I select "Allow", nothing happens.

The text format I sent is:

```
Your OTP is: 12345
@top-level-domain.com #12345 @iframe-domain.com
```

The text format seems to be fine since it's prompting the overlay. But I'm not sure why the DOMException is occurring on page load. Any insight on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you find any solution?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebOTP_API#controlling_access_to_the_api

Maybe you just forgot to add "src" attribute to iframe or set Permissions-Policy header
For example:
HTTP:

```
Permissions-Policy: otp-credentials=(self "https://embedded.com")
```

HTML:

```
<iframe src="https://embedded.com/..." allow="otp-credentials"> ... </iframe>
```

Comment: Анатолий Иванов, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)